# What is $X_l$ here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[convergence of sequence of random variables and cauchy sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627005/convergence-of-sequence-of-random-variables-and-cauchy-sequences/627166#627166)

I recently got the same problem that the linked post asks. I understand the accepted answer except the same point that is described in the first comment of it.
The second comment gives an answer for it, but I'm confused with that. What is $X_l$ here? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: Probably because the way your question is phrased requires extra work for the reader to figure out what you're truly asking (by clicking a link and reading through comments for the point you're referring to; i did not down vote by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small typo, he forgot to add "for all $l \ge n_k$".

For any $k$ let $\varepsilon_k=\delta_k=2^{-k}.$ Then by assumption there exists $n_k$ such that for all $l, m \ge n_k,$ $P(|X_l-X_m| \ge \varepsilon_k) \le \delta_k$. In particular, for all $l\ge n_k,$
$$
P(|X_l-X_{n_k}| \ge 2^{-k}) \le 2^{-k}.
$$

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. But then how does it imply that there is a limit $X$ for the subsequence $X_{n_k}$?

Comment: By Borel-Cantelli you get that $X_{n_k}$ is a.s. Cauchy. 
Let $D\subset \Omega$ be a subset of probability $1$ such that for all $\omega\in D,$   $X_{n_k}(\omega)$ is Cauchy. Let $\omega \in D$, then $X_{n_k}(\omega)$ converges, since it is a deterministic Cauchy sequence. Call its limit $X(\omega).$ Outside of $D$ define $X$ however you like. Then $$X_{n_k}\to X\; a.s.$$

Comment: @Derivative here's a more detailed explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/960896/451957

Comment: Thanks, that link was really helpful.